# Relative velocity problem trick

Tags: kinematics

There used to be a river man problem where the swimming speed of man in still water was provided along with speed of river current.Now we had to find the angle at which he should swim for minimum drift in order to reach the opposite shore while crossing the river.Usually we used to apply our concept of maximisation or minimisation.One day my teacher told of a trick...it was like this...for minimum drift, the man's net velocity should be tangent to a semicircle drawn comprising all possible directions in which the man could swim. I have never really understood why should it be a tangent like that...can somebody help me out in this?

Comment: Why would you use some "trick" when you can use velocity vectors and solve this problem with a very little bit of trig?

Comment: That's always a method...i am just curious to know how the trick(i mentioned above) actually works!